# javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException when sending 0 in field

Tags: java, constraints

I have generated some java proxy classes via command

***wsimport -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -keep -verbose https://myservice?wsdl***

then i have integrated it in my java application. Service is working fine.
One problem i am getting is i am getting following error when sending 0 in one long field (third parameter). Don't know from where this internal constraint is added as there isn't any thing in wsdl

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: 1 constraint violation(s) occurred during method validation.

```
Constructor or Method: public .... ...(java.lang.String,int,long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
Argument values: [23123123123, 31, 0, sdfsdf, sdfsdfsdfsdf]
Constraint violations: 
 (1) Kind: PARAMETER
 parameter index: 2
 message: recipientMsisdn must be greater than or equal to 1
 root bean: com.sdsd
 property path: mymethod.arg2
 constraint: @javax.validation.constraints.Min(message=recipientMsisdn must be greater than or equal to 1, payload=[], groups=[], value=1)
```

More over **message=recipientMsisdn must be greater than or equal to 1** is referring first field name while error is due to third field

Note:
I am using jdk 1.7 as it is running on my production server

My wsdl part of the input elements are

```
 <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="recipientMsisdn" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="field2" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="field3" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="field4" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="field5" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
```

My Method Proxy is as following

```
@WebMethod
    @WebResult(targetNamespace = "")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "MyMethod", targetNamespace = "....", className = "....")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "MyApiResponse", targetNamespace = "....", className = "...")

public MyApiResponse MyMethod(
        @WebParam(name = "recipientMsisdn", targetNamespace = "" )
        String recipientMsisdn,
        @WebParam(name = "field2", targetNamespace = "")
        int field2,
        @WebParam(name = "field3", targetNamespace = "")
        long field3,
        @WebParam(name = "field4", targetNamespace = "")
        String field4,
        @WebParam(name = "field5", targetNamespace = "")
        String field5);
```

Comment: They might be using `@Range(min = 1)` for validation from javax.validation.constraints

Comment: This looks intentional - there may be `@Min(1)` validation set on `recipientMsisdn` to prevent 0 or negative values

Comment: Don't know why this constraint was adding which doesn't allow 0 in the field. I have added my wsdl part as well from which my proxy classes was generated.
moreover recepientMsidn is a string field. error is coming due to field3 where i am sending 0

Comment: 1. there seems to be a mismatch in your "parameter order" (recipientMsisdn is not , but field3 is 0). 2. Please have a look/paste the relevant generated java code (destination folder for wsimport(?))

Comment: @xerx593 problem is when i send correct  (value greater then zero ) value every thing works fine. I have added my proxy class web method generated code in the question. Please check

Comment: @EamonScullion I doesn't find anything in generated proxy classes with Min or Range keyword

Comment: Can it be coming from external entity when i am calling there api?

Comment: my point(1.) is: in your example - the long (`field3`) is/seems to be `0`, *but* the error message says: `recipientMsisdn`!. And 2.: some- one/thing must set this(some) validation constraint .... since the error message speaks clear (except (my expectation of) *which* field) ...is there "nothing in between"? ...mapping (, confusing order, and validating ) your  input?

Comment: Anyway i can catch ConstraintViolationException?